# android studio render error

Tags: android, android-studio

I use the android studio 1.0.1 in windows and java sdk version is 1.7.

when the api level is less than 21, that is OK.

[image: The error is below![][1]]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the control bar above the rendered image, there is an option to choose the API to render the image with. It must be hidden under the expand arrows in your case. Simply select a lower API to have it render properly.

API 21 is known to mess with rendering as for now and previous versions will render the layouts properly.

Also, please note that the IDE rendering is NEVER 100% accurate and should not be based on in the production cycle, as concrete system compilations may implement some mechanisms differently.

Comment: Thank you. We have to wait google to solve that problem