# Android Studio rendering error

Tags: android, android-studio

I am newly runnign andrioid studio and I am getting an instead of hello world printed on the screen. The error says there is a rendering problem. I have included the snapshot of the problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae39R.png) Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android studio render error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481499/android-studio-render-error)

Answer (score 0):

Click on: "Automatically add all missing attributes" should solve the problem.

Comment: Show us your complete XML.